# Http POST not triggering a server side event

Tags: php, webhooks, endpoint, server-sent-events

This has got me (and apparently ChatGPT) baffled

I am trying to get a PHP webhook endpoint to trigger a server side event. This works, but not when I try hitting the endpoint with a POST request. To test the POST was being recieved I also logged to a file and that works.

Here's my webhook endpoint:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');

header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');


// Function to send SSE
function sendSSE($data) {
    echo "data: $data\n\n";
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}

sendSSE(json_encode(array("inn" => "inn")));  #1 This sends a server side event

file_put_contents('messages.log', "inn" . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);  #2 This writes to the log file 

$post_data = file_get_contents("php://input");

if( $post_data != null ) {
    
    file_put_contents('messages.log', "post2" . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND); 
    
    sendSSE(json_encode(array("post2" => "post2")));
}


// Check if it's a POST request
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') 
{
    sendSSE(json_encode(array("post" => "post"))); #3 This DOES NOT a server side event
       
    file_put_contents('messages.log', "post" . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);  #4 This DOES write to the log file
} 

?>
```

And here's the client page I want to write the POST data to

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>SSE Client</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="sse-data"></div>
    <script>
        const sseData = document.getElementById('sse-data');
        const source = new EventSource('sse2.php');

        source.onmessage = function(event) {

            console.error("Onmessage received:", event);

            const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
            sseData.innerHTML += '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(data, null, 2) + '</pre>';
        };

        source.onerror = function(event) {
            console.error("EventSource failed:", event);
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've also tried this with no joy

```
$post_data = file_get_contents("php://input");

if( $post_data != null ) {

   file_put_contents('messages.log', "post2" . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND); # WORKS  

   sendSSE(json_encode(array("post2" => "post2")));  # DOES NOT WORK

}
```

Comment: If this PHP script is being fired by a webhook call, then anything echoed from it will be sent back to the system which initiated the call - not to some other user's browser somewhere else (after all, how on earth would it know to echo to that...there's no connection between the two things)

Comment: And if this script is also the one named sse.php which is being called from your web page well...when the web page tries to open the event stream from it, it'll likely find there isn't much of a reply - because naturally _that_ SSE connection to the script didn't send any POST data...that was in a completely different request.

Comment: So you seem to have got into a bit of a muddle with the architecture. What you likely need is _two_ scripts, and some data storage in between. Script 1 is the webhook endpoint - it'll receive the POST data and store it somewhere (e.g. in a database table might be sensible). Script 2 is the SSE feed - this will have a loop which polls the database at intervals to find out if there's any new data been added (you might want to timestamp the data at insertion, to enable this) and, if so, sends an SSE message to the browser.

Comment: Thank you. Time for a rethink... or just a think